# Hibernate - How to restrict the concurrent read of the record by multiple users?

Tags: hibernate, locking

We are using Hibernate 3.6.0. We have requirement of retrieve next available record from the table. How do we control retrieving same record by multiple concurrent users. 
  We need to read the next available record and update the status on column (kind of lock) to avoid next user retrieving the same record. We added Version column on the table (Optimistic lock), but it seems controlling on update.

What is the best solution in Hibernate to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.
Venkat

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried locking the record in question? Hibernate supports pessimistic locking (`SELECT FOR UPDATE`), look at the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-locking).

You might also try optimistic locking, it kind of depends on the level of concurrency you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I am struggling between the Optimistic and Pessimistic solutions. Optimistic controls the updates by using Version column (and timestamp etc..), but I want to get next available record to the 2nd user instead of throwing error on update.  Pessimistic locking seems to have scalability issues.Is there a solution to use Optimistic locking without throwing error on update fails? Do we need to catch the error and retry for next record?

Comment: Maybe, if both pessimistic and optimistic locking are not working for you (BTW don't use timestamps as version columns), try different approach? For example read 100 records in advance and put each record as a task in JMS queue. Then each client picks up a single record from the queue and processes it. No duplication, durability and transactions are available as well. And this solution is completely independent from your persistence layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flag say read (1=true/0=false) and use this flag while retrieving the object like -

```
where read=0
```

after select you can update the read flag to restrict the another user to read this record. if you want - you can use version flag like a read flag, since you update the entity after select version will increment and can be used to differentiate the read/unread records.

Let me know if this helps or I missed your problem entirely.

Comment: We have version column in the table. What happens 2nd user reads the data before first user updates the version? It is going to fail for 2nd user on update. Do we need to capture the error and retry again? I also like Tomasz solution, but hoping Hibernate version solution might simplify the effort and risk. Please let me know. Thanks for the great ideas.

Comment: you need to use synchronization or pessimistic locking but there will be performance penalty, do some testing and see which one is better